# SQL query to get multiple records into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a CSV that I am trying to create and pull data for. The CSV template has multiple columns for Status (IE: Status1, Status2, Status3). Some locations have only one status and some can have up to 3. I am trying to find a way in SQL that I can have 3 status columns and populate those based on the number of records for a location. For example, a location called John's Office could have a status of Ready. Another location called IT Workroom may have 3 statuses, Ready, In-Repair, and In-Use. The columns in the SQL query would look something like this:

```
Location          Status1         Status2        Status3
----------------------------------------------------------
John's Office     Ready
IT Workroom       Ready           In-Repair       In-Use
```

The column names Status1, Status2, etc would be column names that are just made up. I would want to populate Status1 with the first record that returns, regardless of the actual status name. So Status1 would always be populated. Status2 will only be populated if their is a second status.

In the original table that holds this information, it looks like this:

```
LocationName           StatusName
------------------------------------
IT Workroom            In-Repair
IT Workroom            Ready
John's Office          Ready
IT Workroom            In-Use
```

I have tried `PIVOT`, but I realized that this is not what I need as I am not technically aggregating the data.

Comment: It looks like pivot is *exactly* what you need. How do you determin that `in-use` is Status 3 and not Status 2 or Status 1? Is there a list of Status values with a defined ordinal position?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The column names Status1, Status2, etc would be column names that are just made up. I would want to populate Status1 with the first record that returns, regardless of the actual status name. So Status1 would always be populated. Status2 will only be populated if their is a second status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use row number with max case when like this:

```
select LocationName, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN StatusName ELSE NULL END) Status1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN StatusName ELSE NULL END) Status2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN StatusName ELSE NULL END) Status3 
from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LocationName ORDER BY LocationName, StatusName) RowNum
    from #data
) Recs
group by LocationName
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly for me and I got to learn about `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY`. I appreciate your time!

Comment: @shockin779, why to use a solution with a derived table when it could be done in one shot via a single `SELECT` ?

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is not necessary as it's the default, although it does make it more explicit

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution mimicking PIVOT operation.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, LocationName VARCHAR(30), StatusName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('IT Workroom', 'In-Repair'),
('IT Workroom', 'Ready'),
('John''s Office', 'Ready'),
('IT Workroom', 'In-Use');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT  LocationName
   , MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Ready' THEN StatusName ELSE '' END) [Status1]
   , MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'In-Repair' THEN StatusName ELSE '' END) [Status2]
   , MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'In-Use' THEN StatusName ELSE '' END) [Status3]
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY LocationName
ORDER BY LocationName;
```

**Output**

```
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| LocationName  | Status1 |  Status2  | Status3 |
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| IT Workroom   | Ready   | In-Repair | In-Use  |
| John's Office | Ready   |           |         |
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple solution considering you have just 3 different types of statuses so the code is not so much replicated.

```sql
insert into new_locations (
    select distinct location,
        case when location in (select distinct location from old_locations where status = 'ready') then 'ready' else '' end,
        case when location in (select distinct location from old_locations where status = 'active') then 'active' else '' end,
        case when location in (select distinct location from old_locations where status = 'dead') then 'dead' else '' end
    from old_locations
);
```

SQL is quite handy and this is just the case where you can kind of cheat with using bit of code replication, it is very simple to understand and does its job. There usually is some pure SQL solution for this kind of problems without need of using T-SQL or other sql 'upgrades'.